# Form API: Show/Hide/Select option based on a previous option

Tags: forms, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest method for conditional fields in a form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/481/easiest-method-for-conditional-fields-in-a-form)

Essentially I have 2 select fields on a form:

**EDIT**: I should mention, this is an entirely custom form built with Form API, I'm not modifying a core/contrib form.

- Type

  - Global
  - Regional
- City

  - Any
  - London
  - New York
  - Paris
  - LA

If Type:Global is selected, then the City field is hidden and City:Any is selected.

If Type:Regional is selected, then City is revealed, City:London selected and City:Any hidden.

Is there a Drupal or Form API compliant method to achieve this or is it simply a case of loading a JS file with drupal_add_js and writing entirely custom JS?

If it's simply custom JS/JQuery no need to write it out for me, I can handle that, but I would like to try and stick to the standard and best practices if there are any for my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using AHAH on your Form API. The module [AHAH Helper](http://drupal.org/project/ahah_helper) may be very useful for you... take a look there...